# Outbound Email bounce processing - is it possible to set requires SSL?

Tags: tridion

I'm configuring Outbound Email Bounce processing using Tridion 2011, but am getting the following error:

```
errCannotAccessPOP3Account

StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.OutboundEmail.Services.BounceProcessor.BounceInbox.ProcessPop3Mailbox(XmlDocument analyzedMessages)
   at Tridion.OutboundEmail.Services.BounceProcessor.BounceInbox.ProcessMessages()
   at Tridion.OutboundEmail.Services.BounceProcessor.BounceProcessorService.ProcessItem(UserContext userContext, BounceInbox inbox)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Utilities.OutboundEmailServiceBase`1.Process(UserContext userContext)
```

In OutboundEmail.xml there is a section to configure Bounce Processing:

```
<BounceProcessing>
    <PollingInterval>300</PollingInterval>
    <Mailbox name="MailBounce">
      <Protocol>POP3</Protocol>
      <Server>pop.gmail.com</Server>
      <Port>995</Port>
      <User></User>
      <Password></Password>
      <ImapFolder></ImapFolder>
      <Forwarding>
        <Server>localhost</Server>
        <Port>25</Port>
        <SenderName>Forwarder</SenderName>
        <SenderAddress>forwarder@localhost</SenderAddress>
        <SuccessSubject></SuccessSubject>
        <SuccessAddress>bounced@localhost</SuccessAddress>
        <SuccessMessage></SuccessMessage>
        <FailedSubject></FailedSubject>
        <FailedAddress>replies@localhost</FailedAddress>
        <FailedMessage></FailedMessage>
      </Forwarding>
    </Mailbox>
  </BounceProcessing>
```

However, there is not a section to enable SSL, which might be the cause of my error?

Is it possible to enable SSL for Tridion Outbound Email Bounce processing?

Comment: Can you specify which version of Tridion/Outbound Email you are using?

Comment: Sorry - glaring omission! Tridion 2011.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outbound E-mail doesn't specifically handle SSL, an enhancement request has been created to remedy this. However, Outbound E-mail uses Chilkat software, whose documentation seems to indicate that SSL should be chosen automatically when using port 995 (though I've not tried this). The above shown configuration doesn't actually contain a user / password, I imagine you've actually tried it with credentials?

Comment: Hi Robert, yes I just removed the credentials so I could safely post it here. It may not be the SSL that is causing the problem if you think Chillkat should default to using that on port 995. The error message doesn't give much away!

Comment: Hi Dave, I've done a quick test to see if the Bounce Processor can actually connect to port 995 over SSL, which seems to be working like documented by Chilkat. The fact that the error message only shows 'errCannotAccessPOP3Account' is a known issue that was fixed in 2011 SP1.
The only thing I can tell you is that when you get this error, it is indeed related to connection problems.